# Rails Select Box form helper for multiple booleans

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, boolean, form-helpers

Is there a way to use a select box in a rails form for multiple booleans? Let's say I have three weather conditions: Clear, Cloudy, Rainy that are each boolean. Can I put them in one select box titled "Weather", and when one of them is picked that one becomes 'true'?

Answer (score 1):

To me, I see this as two different actions.

1) The user making a selection from a selection_box helper on the form. That variable gets set to the resource :current_weather and stored in the database.

2) After submit button is clicked then is more logic processed in the controller or through a class method. Let's say it was in the 'update' portion of CRUD in a weather tracker.

```
def update
  @tracker = Tracker.find(params[:id])
    if @tracker.current_weather == "Clear"
    #do this
    end
end
```

Maybe this will give you some ideas. Good luck!